# Help identifying multidimensional integral with product of exponents

Tags: integration, transformation

I am looking for literature on the type of multidimensional integral below

$$F(a_1,...,a_D)=\int_{Q} f(q_1,...,q_D) \prod_{d=1}^D[(a_d)^{q_d}] d^{D-1}q $$

The integral domain Q is a D-1 dimensional hyperplane within a D-Euclidean space for which
$$ q_1+...+q_D=1 $$

I'm sorry in advance if this was asked before (I searched and couldn't find posts on this topic), or if my question is too general. This popped-up while working on field theory and I don't even know what keywords to search in Google... Any information will help, like integrability conditions, known identities, etc.

For clarity, in two dimensions this will be a line integral

$$F(a,b)=\sqrt 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(q) a^q b^{1-q} dq $$

Comment: In the last week I'm trying to approach the 2D system first, with a strategy to extrapolate into 3D and higher dimensions

Comment: I assume that the space of solutions can be spanned by functions for which 0<=q<=1. Those functions are continuous for a=0 and/or b=0. I then assume that f(q) is actually periodic between 0 and 1 and span it using Fourier series, this can give me a basis set to span the solutions-space. However I found that each basis-function in the set diverges when a,b go to infinity.
So my last and more complicated step is to find a weight-function g(a,b) to use for an inner-product operator between the basis-functions that will allow normalization. Preferably it will also make them orthogonal.